# How to treat invalid escape sequence in json with python?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I seem to receive invalid json from a website.
The error is this invalid escape sequence:

```
{"typ":"R\xc3\xbccken Gym "}
```

This leads to an error when decoding:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Invalid \escape: line 1 column 1238 (char 1237)
```

Is there a way to treat this in some way or do I have to replace such invalid escape sequences in advance? And to be honest, I'm not sure why this is invalid.
Thank you!

Comment: *JSON doesn’t support \xBA*, only \uDCBA — ideally, fix the broken non-JSON source, if that can’t be done, one option is to do text replace first, before attempting to parse: \xBA -> \u00BA YMMV. The _only_ edge-case is that the \ itself can’t be escaped (eg, foo\\xAB should not be transformed). This can be done by a regular expression.

Comment: @user2864740 Thanks! Is this just a different encoding if \xBA is used instead of \u00BA?

Comment: See https://www.json.org/json-en.html for valid rules.

Comment: JSON doesn’t understand \x escapes; \u00BA refers to the same character as \xBA, in contexts that understand the latter .. like Python string literals (http://python-ds.com/python-3-escape-sequences); any \x can be converted to \u, although the reverse is not true.

Comment: It deserialises without error for me `json.loads('{"typ":"R\xc3\xbccken Gym "}')` -> `{'typ': 'RÃ¼cken Gym '}`

Comment: Get the response in bytes (`.content` in `requests`) and do `json.loads(response.content.decode('utf-8'))` → `{'typ': 'Rücken Gym '}`.

Comment: In the more general case, if you can guess what the string means, convert it to proper JSON before passing it to `json.loads()` or similar.